# How to create dynamic roles and authorizations on MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-roles

I use C#-MVC3 (for web).

I want to create a list of operations to do in the site (for example  - open a new article, comment on an article, etc.) and the site's administrator will create roles (administrator, articles-administrator, editor, guest, etc..) and for every roles -  to choose which operation it can do (from the list).

I wanted to use "Roles" and "Authorize" attributes, but it's not dynamic.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You could create an AuthorizationFilter and implement this to include the dynamic checking of your roles.

For an example of using this : http://geekswithblogs.net/brians/archive/2010/07/08/implementing-a-custom-asp.net-mvc-authorization-filter.aspx

Please note that the above example uses a static list of roles, but shows the basic setup of an AuthorizationFiter. This can easily be adapted by modifying the OnAuthorization() method.

Comment: I'm not sure how it helps me.. Let's say I have a role "MyRole" and the site's admin chooses to let this role to edit page_1 and view page_2. I can't use "Authorize" attribute before the actions because I don't know what the site's admin will choose, so how can I handle it?